# Evaluate a Number head as a constant function

Tags: core-language, functional-style

I wanted to use the parameters of a function in a distributive way, so for example

```
In[1]:= Through[(Cos+Sin)[x]]
Out[1]:= Cos[x]+Sin[x]
```

It works without problems however.

```
In[2]:= Through[(Cos+Cos)[x]]
Out[2]:= 2[x] Cos[x]
```

It believes that 2 is a function, I could use a replace rule to replace 2[x_] specifically into 2, but how can I do it for all Numbers?, is there any way to replace any form of *Number*[x] into *Number*?

Comment: However it seems it would be really hard to use through as what my intuition tells me it would work, when you start adding more abstractions. For example Through[(Cos + a Cos[x])] returns:  Cos[x] + (a Cos)[x]

Comment: Would `Through[(Cos + Cos)[x]] /. {h_[x_] /; NumberQ[h] :> h, Times[c_., h_][x_] /; NumberQ[c] :> c h[x]}` suit your needs?

Comment: @J.M. it worked really well, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [`Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) + [`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html) combination to prevent `Plus` from evaluating:

```
Through[Inactivate[Cos + Cos][x]] // Activate
```

> ```
> 2 Cos[x]
> ```

Also

```
Replace[Through[(Cos + Cos)[x]], a_ /; IntegerQ[Head[a]] :> Head[a], All]
```

> ```
> 2 Cos[x]
> ```